# making simple sql query count

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

I have database structure like this>

```
ID |  Party_Code |  Trade_Qty | Market_Rate
-------------------------------------------    
 1     8070            5           10.50
 2     8745            15          80.35
 3     8070            6           45.60
```

This is just the sample data. Actually this table contains 40000 rows.

As from this sample we can see that `Party_Code` columns can have repeated values.

I am trying to find the `count` of `distinct` party codes.

For that I tried following two queries which failed:

```
select count(distinct(Party_Code)) from tradeFile
```

and

```
select distinct(count(Party_Code)) from tradeFile
```

Both of these queries failed.

I want to know where I am making mistake?

What is the way to write such queries?

Comment: it's working http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6efbd/1

Comment: really its working. And its logically fine also. But its showing me nothing[0] for SQLServer 2005

Comment: don't use distinct you just need to count(partycodes) group by partycodes say like *select count(partycode) group by partycode*

Comment: @TonyShih : previously it was showing me 0, but now with this query its showing me nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(distinct Party_Code) from tradeFile
```

Comment: what does count(*) return?

Answer (score 0):

When using the Count function, it is best to use it with a Group By clause:

`select count(*) as Quantity 
from tradeFile
Group By Party_Code`